# How to reorder factor for all groups in one variable by frequency of one group in a different variable

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm creating a graph of the number of people who've done a thing (Yes/Maybe/No) within four different groups (A/B/C/D).

I would like to plot group on the x axis, but order the groups from left to right in descending order of those who did the thing (Yes). I need to do this for a large dataset so specifying the levels manually with fct_relevel() would be quite time consuming.

Example data

```
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(1)

df <- 
  tibble::tibble(
    group = c(rep("A", 5), rep("B", 5), rep("C", 5), rep("D", 5)),
    fill = sample(c("Yes", "Maybe", "No"), size = 20, replace = T),
    value = round(runif(20, 0, 10)))
```

Which we can plot as

```
df %>% 
  ggplot(
    aes(
      x = group,
      fill = fill,
      y = value)) +
    geom_col()
```

[image]

What I'd like to do is order the group variable so it goes in descending order for only the Yes values, from C to D to A to B.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `forcats::fct_reorder()` to order by prevalence of `"Yes"` values.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- df %>%
  mutate(group = fct_reorder(group, fill == "Yes", .fun = mean))

levels(df$group)
# "B" "D" "A" "C"
```

This orders by the proportion of `"Yes"`es; change the `.fun` argument to `sum` if you want to base it on the raw number.